# PrestaShop: Create new cart rule using custom code

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a code to create new cart rule, it works great, but there's one issue, the restriction by product is not working... 
Hoping someone can help, I tried looking the PrestaShop classes and controllers, and I tried to replicate, but this is what I got to and didn't work.

```
    $coupon = new Discount();
    $coupon->quantity = 1;
    $coupon->quantity_per_user = 1;
    $coupon->id_discount_type = 2;// reduction amount
    $coupon->value = '10';

    $coupon->id_customer = 1;

    $coupon->minimum_amount = 0;
    $coupon->minimum_amount_currency = 1;
    $coupon->minimum_amount_tax = 0;
    $coupon->minimum_amount_shipping = 0;
    $coupon->quantity = 1;
    $coupon->quantity_per_user = 1;

    $coupon->product_restriction = 1;
    $coupon->product_rule_group[] = 1;
    $coupon->product_rule_group_1_quantity = 1;
    $coupon->product_rule_1[] = 1;
    $coupon->product_rule_1_1_type = 'products';
    $coupon->product_rule_select_1_1[] = 9;

    $coupon->reduction_percent = 100;
    $coupon->reduction_amount = 0;
    $coupon->reduction_currency = 1;
    $coupon->reduction_tax = 0;
    $coupon->apply_discount_to = 'specific';
    $coupon->reductionProductFilter = '191072 Air Freshener Refill';
    $coupon->reduction_product = 6;
    $coupon->free_gift = 0;


    $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $coupon->date_from = $start_date;

    $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //some end date
    $coupon->date_to = $end_date;

    $gen_pass = strtoupper(Tools::passwdGen(8));
    $vouchercode = 'somecode';
    $name_v = $vouchercode.'-'.$gen_pass;

    $namelang = array();
    $namelang[1] = $name_v;
    $namelang[2] = $name_v;;


    //Add Name array
    $coupon->name = $namelang;


    $current_language = 1;

    $coupon->id_customer = 1;


    // fixed bug for currency
    $coupon->reduction_currency = 1;
    $coupon->minimum_amount_currency = 1;

    $code_v = $vouchercode.'-'.$gen_pass;
    $coupon->code = $code_v;

    //$coupon->minimal = $coupon->value;
    $coupon->active = 1;
    //$coupon->cart_display = 1;
    //$coupon->cart_rule_restriction = 0;
    $coupon->description = '';
    $coupon->highlight = 1;


    $coupon->add();
```

Comment: Have you added some data to table cart_rule_product_rule_group, cart_rule_product_rule and cart_rule_product_rule_value you can see afterAdd in AdminCartRulesControllerCore controller
i think this code have no sens
      $coupon->product_rule_group_1_quantity = 1;
    $coupon->product_rule_1[] = 1;
    $coupon->product_rule_1_1_type = 'products';
    $coupon->product_rule_select_1_1[] = 9;

Answer (score 1):

We recommend you to use following code to create a cart rule.

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule_shop
                set id_cart_rule = ' . (int) $cart_rule_id . ', id_shop = ' . (int) $this->context->shop->id);

        Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule_lang
            set id_cart_rule = ' . (int) $cart_rule_id . ', id_lang = ' . (int) $this->context->language->id . ', 
            name = "' . strip_tags($coupon_name) . '"');

        Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule_product_rule_group
            set id_product_rule_group = NULL, id_cart_rule = ' . (int) $cart_rule_id . ', 
            quantity = 1');

        $product_rule_group_id = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();

        Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule_product_rule
            set id_product_rule = NULL, id_product_rule_group = ' . (int) $product_rule_group_id . ', 
            type = "products"');

        $product_rule_id = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();

        Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_rule_product_rule_value
            set id_product_rule =' . (int) $product_rule_id . ', id_item = ' . (int) $id_product . '');
```

Answer (score 0):

i know it doesn't matter now but, anyways, if you're looking for a way to tie or add products to a specific cart rule, this might help

```
$products = [1 => "32232", 2 => "23232", 3 => "45343"];
```

So, after you `$cartrule->add()` you get, `$cartRuleId = $cartrule->id`

```
    $coupon->product_restriction = 1; //enable product restriction

    $coupon->reduction_product = -2; // write this only if you want the discount to be applied on the products in the cart and not the whole cart

    (new Cart( $cart->id) )->addCartRule( (int) $cartRuleId); // apply the cart rule to this existing cart

    # first, save `id_cart_rule` & `quantity` and get id_product_rule_group
    Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule_group` (`id_cart_rule`, `quantity`)
    VALUES ('.(int)$cartRuleId.', "'.(int)$qty.'")');
    $id_product_rule_group = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();

    # second, save `id_product_rule_group` & `type` and get id_product_rule
    Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule` (`id_product_rule_group`, `type`)
    VALUES ('.(int)$id_product_rule_group.', "'.$type.'")');
    $id_product_rule = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();

    # finally, using id_product_rule assign products
    foreach ($products as $id) {
        $values[] = '('.(int)$id_product_rule.','.(int)$id.')';
    }
    $values = array_unique($values);
    if (count($values)) {
        Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule_product_rule_value` (`id_product_rule`, `id_item`) VALUES '.implode(',', $values));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to engage in complex codes, this method may help you:

1. create Sample disabled coupon with your restrictions on admin panel
2. create object of your Sample coupon on your php file
3. **clone** object to newObject
4. change (code and active and etc) then add new coupon from it